# Как правильно посчитать среднее средних?

Tags: математика

Есть необходимость посчитать средне значение между показателями. Хочу быть уверенным что этот способ справедлив. Когда считаю другим, то данные разные.

Есть стока a и в....таких строк 4. Как я делаю: а/в = х. Затем получаю свой х для каждой строки и того (х+х+х+х)/4 = мой ответ. Если делать (а+а+а+а)/4 = х. (в+в+в+в)/4 = у. х/у = мой ответ(только числа уже не те что в первый раз).

По сути мне нужно просто найти - во сколько раз А больше В в среднем для группы строк. Вот какой их этих методов справедлив?

Comment: действия с дробями вроде в третьем классе проходят. Или сейчас уже в четвертом?

Comment: а причем тут дроби если вопрос и порядке подсчета среднего...либо для каждой строки считать отношение а и в и потом среднее их вывести..или отдельно сплюсовать все а и все в и потом найти отношение сплюсованых результатов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> а причем тут дроби

Дроби тут при том, что Ваш первый вариант это:

```
(a1/b1 + a2/b2 + a3/b3 + a4/b4) / 4 == 
  (a1*b2*b3*b4 + a2*b1*b3*b4 + a3*b1*b2*b4 + a4*b1*b2*b3) / (b1*b2*b3*b4) / 4
```

а второй:

```
(a1 + a2 + a3 + a4) / (b1 + b2 + b3 + b4)
```

Есть разница?

Вам нужен первый вариант.

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз на ютубе начал повторят весь курс математики:) Вот деление дробей тока сегодня открыл)